# Backbone search (always not found)

Tags: javascript, search, backbone.js, model-view-controller

my searchform with backbone works.. except it always says that the item is not found so I think I always send an empty array so yes, then it's logic it won't find anything.

My searchresult view:

```
var ArtikelSearchResultsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#searchResults',
  render: function ( query_encoded ) {
    var query = decodeURIComponent(query_encoded.replace(/\+/g, "%20"));

    var result_artikels = _.filter(this.model.models, function (artikel_model) {
      var artikel = artikel_model.attributes;

      for (var key in artikel) {
        if ( artikel[key].toLowerCase().indexOf( query.toLowerCase() ) >= 0 )
        {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    });

    // Show results
    var template = $("#search-results").html();
    var result_html = _.template( template, { artikels: result_artikels, query: query } );

    this.$el.html( result_html );
  }
});
```

My router sends this:

```
searchResults: function(query){
      artikelSearchView.render(query);
      var artikelSearchResultsView = new ArtikelSearchResultsView({ model: Artikel });
      artikelSearchResultsView.render(query);

    }
```

Artikel is in this case:

```
var Artikel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: 'api/items.json',
  defaults: {
        titel: 'Titel niet opgegeven',
        url_titel: 'unieke sleutel urltitel',
        img_path: 'geen image toegevoegd',
        commentaar: 'Commentaar niet opgegeven',
        categorie: 'Categorie niet opgegeven',
        waardering: 0,
        artikel: 'Artikel niet opgegeven'
    },
    initialize: function(){

      if(!this.get('description')){
        var lazy = 'This user was too lazy too add a description';
        this.set('description', lazy);
      }
    }
});
```

Full code: http://pastebin.com/Y9zi6aGH (Awere that I use Artikel and Artikels in different ways, I know it's bad practice but that's the way I go for now) So my question is: Can someone fix me this so I get searchresult? If I press "a" that should give allmost all my objects but it gives me nothing in results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code in order to work :

1- In your view ArtikelSearchResultsView, I have bound it's model (collection) reset event to it's render method, thus once it's model is reset from the server it call it's render method :

```
  var ArtikelSearchResultsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#searchResults',
  initialize: function(){
      this.model.bind('reset', this.render, this);
  } ...
```

2- change

```
var artikels = new Artikels();
var artikel = new Artikels();
```

to

```
var artikels = new Artikels();
var artikel = new Artikel();
```

3- And finally change your router :

```
searchResults: function(query){
    var artikelSearchResultsView = new ArtikelSearchResultsView({ model: artikels });
    artikels.fetch();
}
```

I have also removed the filtering from ArtikelSearchResultsView render method in order to test it, now the 'this.model.models' is populated with the data you receive from the server.